# Gmail Python API: Build service using access token

Tags: python

My flow is such that I already have the access token available in my backend server. So basically I was using the REST Apis until now for getting all user messages. However, I would like to use the Gmail API batch requests to improve on performance. I see that it is non-trivial to use python requests to do so. The gmail api client for python on the other hand does not seem to have a option where I can use the access token to get the results. Rather I need to use the authorization code which is unavailable to me. Can someone help me solve this?

Thanks,
Azeem

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the Gmail API in your project on Google Developer Console to get the API key which will have separate billing cost involved.